# How to render duplicated @ApiResponse code with swagger-springmvc?

Tags: swagger

Using library:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mangofactory</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-springmvc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

@ApiResponse stated as below:

```
@ApiResponses(value= {
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "TEST 1"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "TEST 2")
})
```

The JSON output shows:

```
{"code":400,"message":"TEST 2","responseModel":"Void"}
```

Expected output is actually:

```
{"code":400,"message":"TEST 2","responseModel":"Void"},{"code":400,"message":"TEST 1","responseModel":"Void"},
```

Is there anyway to resolve this?

Issue also raised in https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/686

Answer (score 4):

Per the [2.0 spec](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/2.0.md%23operationObject) the response code is unique. Even if not explicitly stated, just based on the fact that it's a key in the responses collection.

So based on that [springfox](http://www.springfox.io) will not support this feature.

The alternative is to describe all the conditions that  might cause a 400 status code, within the same response message.

Comment: I'll add and say that the reason for it is that it just doesn't make sense to have multiple messages for a response code, documentation wise. It doesn't provide proper information to the consumer.

Comment: The code maybe unique but not the possible responses. E.g.
403 Forbidden {reason: "Insufficient permissions"} and 403 Forbidden {reason: "quota exeeded"}

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar in that I have 1 controller action that will return different response bodies depending on the 'version' header in the request. it would be nice to decorate a single controller action with multiple versioned responses. i have not come up with a way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Nils El-Himoud. It would be helpful to document not just the HTTP status codes but also the messages that may be associated with them. One use case:  the API endpoint applies multiple validations to the input and returns 400 with a unique message for each validation.  It would be great to document the validations via multiple @APIRESPONSE entries, each showing one of the validation messages.